# javascritp: Function - convert string to function: how to control the execution time

Tags: javascript, eval

I am using Function to convert a user supplied string to a function

I dont want user to misuse it by running infinite loops etc

How can I exit the eval if the execution time exceeds 1sec

eg:

```
try:
  var func = Function("a","b"," some infinite loop here; return 10")
  CheckTIme(var a = func(5,6))
catch:
  console.log("sorry script taking more time")
```

Comment: just.... don't eval user-provided code, it's very dangerous

Answer (score 0):

You would need a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) with which your program communicate through `message.data`. Now, because of a little constraint on that `data` possibility, I had to put the `eval` function result in an array before posting it back. So the main program could look like this:

```
var safEval = new Worker("/eval.js");

// if eval.js send back result witin 1sec,
// stop the deadline timer and show the result & the time it took
safEval.onmessage = function(message) {
  clearTimeout(t);
  console.log(messsage.data[0])
  console.timeEnd('eval');
  safEval.terminate();
}
// Go
console.time("eval");
safEval.postMessage(userSuppliedString);

// Terminate if it takes more than 1sec
var t = setTimeout(function() {
  safEval.terminate();
  console.log("sorry script taking more time");
}, 1000);
```

Then, the `/eval.js` or any other **file on the same web site** as your generated page, could look like this:

```
onmessage = function(message) {
  try {
    postMessage([eval(message.data)]);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: is this possible in chrome

Comment: also if i am running the script only on client browser, then should i worried, it may hand his browser, if he runs some infinite loop,

Comment: All the scripts here run on client browser or side. The only constraint here is that both your main page generator and your Worker must reside on the same site.